# $\sum_{n = 1}^{D - 1} \frac{n}{D - n}$ written as a function of $D$?

Tags: summation

$$\sum_{n = 1}^{D - 1} \frac{n}{D - n}$$

Is it possible to reduce this summation to a function of $D$?

Comment: Let $$f(D) = \sum_{n = 1}^{D - 1} \frac{n}{D - n}$$ Then $f$ is already a function of $D$. Are you asking for a **closed form** for the summation?

Answer (score 1):

$$\sum_{n = 1}^{D - 1} \frac{n}{D - n}\\
=\sum_{n=1}^{D-1}\left(  -1 + \frac{D}{D-n}\right)\\
=-D+1 + D\sum_{n=1}^{D-1}\frac1{D-n} \\
=-D+1 + D\sum_{m=1}^{D-1}\frac1{m} \\
= -D+1 + D H_{D-1}$$
where $H_n$ is the $n$th harmonic number.